# Meaning of "[doing] what is evil in the sight of the Lord"

Tags: hebrew, judges

I'm working through the Old Testament, book by book, and have arrived at Judges, where I anticipate seeing a certain phrase again and again:

> 7 And the people of Israel **did what was evil in the sight of the LORD**.

For the first time, a question has arisen in my mind as to whether this means:

*Israel did what, by God's moral standards, is evil*

...or...

*Israel did evil things plainly and directly in God's sight*

Perhaps I'm splitting hairs here (after all, it could easily be both), but given that it comes up again and again to describe decades of ridiculous wickedness on the part of Israel, I wonder whether anybody can shed light on whether the language points in one direction or another, and enrich my understanding of this key phrase.

Answer (score 2):

This expression occurred when Israel was punished with wondering in the desert.  The expression is used for why YHWH brought judgment>

> And the LORD’s anger was kindled against Israel, and he made them wander in the wilderness forty years, until all the generation that had done evil in the sight of the LORD was gone.
> (Num. 32:13, ESV)

The expression is used in Deuteronomy telling the consequences of such.  Making images is mentioned there.

> When you father children and children’s children, and have grown old in the land, if you act corruptly by making a carved image in the form of anything, and by doing what is evil in the sight of the LORD your God, so as to provoke him to anger,
> (Deut. 4:25, ESV)

It refers to making the Golden Calf.

> Then I lay prostrate before the LORD as before, forty days and forty nights. I neither ate bread nor drank water, because of all the sin that you had committed, in doing what was evil in the sight of the LORD to provoke him to anger.
> (Deut. 9:18, ESV)

Breaking the covenant; worshipping other gods:

> If there is found among you, within any of your towns that the LORD your God is giving you, a man or woman who does what is evil in the sight of the LORD your God, in transgressing his covenant, 3 and has gone and served other gods and worshiped them, or the sun or the moon or any of the host of heaven, which I have forbidden,
> (Dt 17:2–3, ESV)

In Judges often the evil done was not explained (Judges 3:12; 4:1; 6:1; 13:1), but it is summarized near the beginning of Judges, serving the Baals, the Ashtaroth, and other gods:

> And the people of Israel did what was evil in the sight of the LORD and served the Baals. 12 And they abandoned the LORD, the God of their fathers, who had brought them out of the land of Egypt. They went after other gods, from among the gods of the peoples who were around them, and bowed down to them. And they provoked the LORD to anger. 13 They abandoned the LORD and served the Baals and the Ashtaroth.
> (Judges 2:11–13, ESV)

Israel served Baals and Astaroth (Judges 3:7).  Then, description of the evil is expanded:

> The people of Israel again did what was evil in the sight of the LORD and served the Baals and the Ashtaroth, the gods of Syria, the gods of Sidon, the gods of Moab, the gods of the Ammonites, and the gods of the Philistines. And they forsook the LORD and did not serve him.
> (Judges 10:6, ESV)

The covers through Judges, but the expression continues throughout the Tanakh (Old Testament).  So what Israel did that was evil in God's eyes was breaking the covenant, in particular it was ususally worshipping other gods. This is the answer with respect to Judges.

Answer (score 0):

#### What does it mean to “[do] what is evil in the sight of the Lord”?

**A.** Israel did what, by God's moral standards, is evil? Or, 
**B.** Israel did evil things plainly and directly in God's sight?

Answer: **Israel did both**.

However we need to recognize what "evil" actually is. It is not merely a "thing." Now, "sin" is defined as lawlessness in John's First Letter:

> **1 Jn. 3:4**: "Everyone who practices sin also practices lawlessness; and sin is lawlessness."

Therefore, we should understand that "evil" is the manifestation of lawlessness committed by a conscious, responsible agent.

We learn of how this may occur early and often in the Bible. Simply *looking* at the Tree of Knowledge was not a sin. Neither was *touching* it. However, once Eve *ate* of the Tree ["you shall not eat"], she violated God's only law, and her disobedience gave birth to lawlessness — evil.

Having defined "evil", suppose we read what biblical scholar, James Coffman [writes](https://www.studylight.org/commentaries/eng/bcc/judges.html) about the nation of Israel during the time of the Judges:

> Not only did the Israelites associate with the residual pagan elements of Canaan, they made slaves of them. They began to intermarry with them. They indulged in the worship of their fertility gods with its shameful licentiousness. They forgot God, and in time, became just as evil as the Canaanites whom God had driven out before them. The repeated deliverances and restorations of Israel during the period of the Judges was God's way of preventing the total ruin and loss of the Chosen People.

Those who disobeyed God in Judges through their lawless deeds sinned against Him because *all sin is against God*, and this is evil.

We might note the words of Christ from Matthew's Gospel, regarding "lawlessness":

> **Matthew 7:22-23**: “Many will say to Me on that day, ‘Lord, Lord, did we not prophesy in Your name, and in Your name cast out demons, and in Your name perform many miracles?’ And then I will declare to them, ‘I never knew you; DEPART FROM ME, YOU WHO PRACTICE LAWLESSNESS.’"

Christ affirms that "evil" and "lawlessness" are synonymous. *Any* disobedience to God is evil.

Based on the two questions from the OP, (A) is correct because yes, Israel broke God's standards, His Laws, which was evil. It is irrelevant whether we view these laws as "moral". And, (B) is correct because yes, Israel did this directly in God's sight: every act ever committed on earth is observed — seen plainly and directly — by God.

Unfortunately, I am unable to provide a further (Hebrew or other linguistic) interpretation that might shed more light on the questions by the OP.

Comment: To those who decide to down-vote in anonymity, it sure would be helpful if you might at least leave a comment so that responses such as this one can be edited and improved.

Comment: Agreed. The answer doesn't so much directly answer my question as to build an argument for saying that both answers are correct, which is reasonable. To clarify, I was hoping somebody knew some sort of Hebrew-linguistic thing that would shed light on whether the statement favoured one interpretation or another, but it's quite possible no such thing exists in this case. Still, I appreciate the time and effort taken in crafting this answer.

Comment: @omannay Thanks for that. If I can, I'm hoping to improve the answer *to more directly respond to your question* a bit later today. Your feedback is especially helpful.